# $.plugin.function and scoping in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

im a php guy, right now im learning on making my first plugin

heres what im upto

```
$.plugin.method({ 
    test: 'helloworld'
});

$.plugin.method({ 
    test: 'another helloworld'
})
```

heres my function or class ?

```
// class ?
jquery.plugin = function(){
    // variables
    var test = [];

    // function ?
    var method = function(params){
        test[] = params['test']
    }
    console.log(test)
}
```

what im expecting

```
test = ['helloworld','another helloworld']
```

can we do that in javascript ? am i getting it right ?

thanks!

Comment: yeah i did, its empty. let me try again. ah sorry wrong method. updated the question. sorry.

Comment: felix, so $.plugin.method() is an function it self? not calling method inside plugin ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you made `plugin` a **function**, but in the first snippet you are calling `$.plugin.method()` and not `$.plugin()`.

You'd have to make `plugin` an **object** with a `method` property:

```
(function($) {

    // variables
    var test = [];

    $.plugin = {
        method: function(params){
            test.push(params['test']);
            console.log(test)
        }
    }

}(jQuery));
```

The immediate function ensures that `test` is only visible to `$.plugin` itself. You cannot access it from the outside. If you want to do that, you have to make it a property of `$.plugin`:

```
$.plugin = {
    test: [],
    method: function(params){
        this.test.push(params['test']);
        console.log(test)
    }
}
```

---

I suggest you first read a [JavaScript guide *<sup>[MDN guide]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) to learn the basics about [functions *<sup>[MDN guide]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) and [objects *<sup>[MDN guide]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Answer (score 1):

What is $.plugin?  I have no idea what you want, so here goes nothing:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.plugin = {
    // Variable
    test: [],

    // Function
    method: function(params) {
        this.test.push(params['test']);
    }
};

$.plugin.method({
    test: 'helloworld'
});

$.plugin.method({
    test: 'another helloworld'
});

alert($.plugin.test);
</script>
```